# Why 'Expect' is not sending the full command?

Tags: expect

I want to configure default route in a server via below code. My issue here is that the `Expect` is not sending full route command. Looks like the script is truncating the command.

It should send `route add default gw 5.66.0.1` but it is sending `route add defaul`

I am not sure why this happening.

**Code**

```
puts "Sending route add default gw $cv_chassis_gw_ip_1 command"
send -- "route add default gw $cv_chassis_gw_ip_1\r"
sleep 1
expect {
    -timeout $cv_cmd_timeout
    -re "route.*#" { }
    timeout {
        puts "Timeout happend in getting # prompt"
    }
}
sleep 1
```

**Debug Output**

```
Sending route add default gw 5.66.0.1 command
send: sending "route add default gw 5.66.0.1\r" to { exp9 }

expect: does "\n" (spawn_id exp9) match regular expression "route.*#"? no
sh-4.0# 
sh-4.0# route add defaul
expect: does "\nsh-4.0# \r\nsh-4.0# route add defaul" (spawn_id exp9) match regular expression "route.*#"? no
```

Comment: It sent the command correctly. [ Note debug output, `sending "route add default gw 5.66.0.1\r" to { exp9 }`]. While matching the pattern only, at first it might have tried to match up to `route add defaul`. If you check the debug output, it will be checked further for whole output, depends on the timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dinesh.
Actually its server issue,server is not able to read a command fully sometime,i tried doing copy pasting a same command and found that sometime it is not taking full command.
so we can close this thread.